# Add new rows to a gridview before submit to database

Tags: c#, gridview, insert, row

Good afternoon,

I'm developing a form to place orders online.

I get the article from a combobox and get the details of that article using a sql query. So far, so good.

I put that article to a gridview. For one article, it's all ok.

I make the selection of the article, click on insert button, and the article with the details is inserted on the gridview.

My problem is on how to add more rows. When i click the insert button, with a different article and details, i only get one row, with overwritten data.

After all rows are in the gridview, i finally can submit that rows and process the order.

What should i use to add so many rows as i need? ViewState? Session State?

I read some articles, but none of them helped me as i needed.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I use a datatable to store the data.

```
 DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        DT.Columns.Add("Artigo");
        DT.Columns.Add("Descricao");
        DT.Columns.Add("IVA");
        DT.Columns.Add("PU");
        DT.Columns.Add("UN");
        DT.Columns.Add("Qtd");
        DT.Columns.Add("TotalLiq");

        try
        {
            int Qtd = Convert.ToInt32(Quantidade.Text);
            int PrecoUnit = glb._precolente;
            float TotalLiq = Qtd * PrecoUnit;

            string str = "SELECT TOP 1 A.Artigo as Artigo, A.Descricao as Descricao, (SELECT Taxa FROM prisalviani.dbo.Iva WHERE Iva = A.Iva)AS IVA, A.UnidadeBase as UN FROM prisalviani.dbo.ARTIGO A where A.Artigo='" + result.ToString() + "'";

            ListaLentes = Motor.Consulta(ref str);


            while (!ListaLentes.NoFim())
            {
                DT.Rows.Add(ListaLentes.Valor("Artigo"),
                            ListaLentes.Valor("Descricao"),
                            ListaLentes.Valor("IVA"),
                            PrecoUnit,
                ListaLentes.Valor("UN"),
                Qtd,
                TotalLiq
                );
                ListaLentes.Seguinte();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the description you have given is a bit vague, what kind of data structure are you using to hold the order rows? do you want to implement something similar to a shopping basket?

you can implement your own business entities or use a dataset/datatable to hold the new records, you can the keep these objects in the Session.

does it help a bit?

Comment: Edited the question with more details. Yes, it's something like a basket. I insert N rows to the grid, and when i have my selection done i submit and process the order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your datagridview holds 3 cells of type String,

You can use:

```
object [] row1 = new object[] { "StringInCell1","StringInCell2","StringInCell3" }
dataGridView.Rows.Add(row1);
```

And if you need to edit a specific cell you can do it using:

```
dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Value = "newValue";
```